# Android View Client

Tags: android, python-2.7, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient, android-auto

I am new to use android view client and am trying to run a view client program from my system and always getting error like:

```
ERROR: testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise RuntimeError('''ERROR: UiAutomator output contains no valid informatio
n. UiAutomator was killed, no reason given.''' + extraInfo) RuntimeError: 

     ERROR: UiAutomator output contains no valid information. UiAutomat
or was killed, no reason given.
It is known that 'com.android.commands.monkey' conflicts with 'uiautomator'. Please kill it and try again.
```

Is there any workaround I can use as I see UIAutomator dump always gets killed when trying to assign parameters to "VC" in my case:

`vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)`

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind i was able to get it to work by loading new uiautomator and setting up root previlages on my device now am stuck at a point were,

when we do uiautomator dump on unix it is dumping xml along with some warnings and ViewClient wast not able to parse XML file (popping up an error not correct XML format) is there a way i can append it to file and parse it instead of parsing from the terminal window in "viewclient.py"

Comment: Can you please show an example of the error (or malformed xml)? Setting `DEBUG_RECEIVED = True` in `viewclient.py` may also help.

Comment: Hi dtmilano, I am able to get XML dump now, i was trying to get Uiautomator dump from serial port  but found out ViewClient is going to get dump from adb shell and am able to fix it by setting adb root permissions.